# How to update ASP.Net site dll without stopping site

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, publish

Is it possible to update the site dll for a precompiled site without stopping IIS.

Currently, if I try to just copy the new file to overwrite the current file, All users receive runtime errors while the file is being copied.   Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You can upload the file to a separate folder first, then the copy process remotely will take only a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

even if you don't stop, any change to the web.config file, BIN folder, App_Data or App_Code will force the .NET compiler to perform ...

and you will loose any Session variables in memory.

What I do is to use **Session State** in **SQL Mode** and if your system is set up like this, user will remain in the site (after a longer exposition to a page reload)

.NET will still invoke the compiler in order to compile the new set of instructions but soon it is done, all sessions will be read from SQL Server and because they are still there (and not lost with a memory refresh) users will remain in the website with current credentials.

it is a little bit slower than In-Memory Session State, but much more reliable, specially with Shared hosting :) this is the way to increse/decrese the minutes in your session, as Shared hosting do not allow it to change even if you do

```
Session.Timeout = 5;
```

their machine configuration will override everything you do, with SQL Session State, you will be able to set your time as this is all made by SQL Server.

Fell free to read [this article](http://idunno.org/articles/277.aspx) to know how everything is done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @krlzlx [read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1451942/28004), it will say the same and gives you a good post on everything works

Comment: @balexandre what about using ssd for storing credentials at the sql server, and disk for other data storage

Comment: @balexandre Have you got any solution for API hosted on IIS? Could you add some thing about API?

Comment: @balexandre the "this article" link has broken.