# what are inproc variable and how do they make the session faster?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I understand what InProc variables are but how do they make the session faster?
Is it because they have less access time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InProc session is basically kept in memory of the process.

You alternative to use database session will give you the overhead of querying the database, instead of just directly accessing the variables in memory. Yet, it should be unnoticable in smaller apps.

You should consider that having the session in database will give you the advantage to run multiple worker processes and have the same session shared across them.

Answer (score 2):

Check this topic and the answer given by adt.

[Which one is better, InProc or SQL Server, for Session State mode in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688047/which-one-is-better-inproc-or-sql-server-for-session-state-mode-in-asp-net)

InProc keeps data in-memory and SQL persists data to disk. Definitely faster!