# #asp.net difference between profile properties and session state (state server mode or sql server mode)?

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference when I'm using profile properties to share data across pages and when I'm using session and change session state to 
(SQL server mode or state server mode) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447175/sqlserver-vs-stateserver-for-asp-net-session-state-performance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLServer vs StateServer for ASP.NET Session State Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447175/sqlserver-vs-stateserver-for-asp-net-session-state-performance)